# Move ball based on player angle

Tags: java, physics

I am trying to program a simple football game for practice purposes. I am trying to kick the ball forward based on the players position he came from. I found [this question about moving a ball by applying a force](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105015/move-ball-based-on-direction-of-force), but it doesnt help me since it's for Unity and C# and they don't provide any logic on how to do that but only methods working for Unity and C#.

Here I have made an image to explain what I mean if it wasn't clear yet:

[image]

Logic and/or Java code is requested.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are literally asking us to do the work for you, but we aren't. SE users help each other by defining a specific problem others can help to solve. Requesting complete working code samples isn't going to work. Requesting logic design for something requires a starting effort from you in the first place. Have you tried to define a basic logic for it? Can you show us what you tried so far, and where's your issue?

Comment: It wasnt such a complex question that you need to write a 4 row long text where you explain me how stupid I am. The answer below just made the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

On collision, get the position vector of the player and the position vector of the ball.

Position vector ball - position vector player = the direction the ball travels in.

Divide the vector by the magnitude of the vector to get the unit vector (I'm not sure about Java, but C# Unity has a built-in method for this).

Finally multiply that vector by some constant (e.g. kicking strength). Set the ball's velocity to that vector and it should work (not super realistically, but good enough for anyone asking this question).

I don't have experience with Java, hence the lack of code, but the above should be a general solution for just about anything.

Comment: Thanks, thats actually a good start that helped me to solve the problem. I was just stuck at how the logic could look :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what technology you are using but I can propose something :

Save the position from the last frame in a variable so that you have a vector formed by this point and the position in the current frame which is the vector you will use to move the ball

```
//Called each frame
Update()
{
    ball.move(Vector(lastPosition,this.position) * speed)
    lastPosition = this.position
}
```